# Proof that $\mathbb{E} X^k = 0$ for all odd $k$ implies $X$ symmetric for bounded $X$ without characteristic functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm working through the exercises in Terry Tao's *Topics in Random Matrix Theory*, and came across:

> Let $X$ be a bounded real random variable.  Show that $X$ is symmetric if and only if $\mathbb{E}X^k = 0 $ for all positive odd integers $k$.

Clearly, if $X$ is symmetric, then $\mathbb{E} X^k = 0$ for all positive odd integers $k$; for the reverse direction, I can show this using Fourier analysis/characteristic functions:

Since $X$ is bounded, we know by DCT that $$ \mathbb{E} e^{it X} = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{(it)^k \mathbb{E} X^k}{k!} = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^jt^{2j} \mathbb{E} X^{2j}}{(2j)!}$$
where we also used that the odd moments are zero.  This is real for real $t$, which then implies that $$\mathbb{E} e^{-itX} = \overline{\mathbb{E} e^{itX}} = \mathbb{E} e^{itX}.$$

Since $X$ and $-X$ have the same characteristic function, they must also have the same distribution.

Tao states afterwards that "it is also instructive to find a 'real-variable' proof that avoids the use of this function," but I'm unable to find it.  Intuitively, it seems like there must be some sort of exponential moment, because you need to capture the data for all of the moments at the same time.  I'm not sure how to do that without going directly to the characteristic function.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\E{\Bbb E}$Say $-1\le X\le 1$.

If $p$ is an odd polynomial then $\E[p(X)]=0$.

Suppose $f:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R$ is continuous and odd. There exist polynomials $q_n$ which converge to $f$ uniformly. Hence $p_n\to f$ uniformly on $[-1,1]$, if $p_n(t)=(p(t)-p(-t))/2$. But $p_n$ is an odd polynomial, hence $\E[f(X)]=0$.

Now suppose $-1\le a< b\le 1$ and let $f=\Bbb 1_{(a,b)}-\Bbb 1_{(-b,-a)}$. There exist continuous functions $f_n$ with $|f_n|\le 1$ such that $f_n\to f$ pointwise (draw a picture...). So DCT shows that $P(a<X<b)-P(-b<X<-a)=\E[f(X))]=0$.

Comment: Thanks!  You had me at "there exist polynomials $q_n$ which converge to $f$ uniformly."