# Another question about "all odd moments vanish"

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

[Question inspired by [Example of non-degenerate random variable with odd moments = 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3918256/442)  ]

Suppose $X$ is a real random variable such that all odd momenents vanish.
That is $\mathbb E[X^{2n+1}]=0$ for $n=0,1,2,3\cdots$.  Does it follow
that $X$ is symmetrically distributed about $0$?  That is, $X$ and $-X$ have the same
distribution.

Note: the case where $X$ is bounded is found here: [Proof that $\mathbb{E} X^k = 0$ for all odd $k$ implies $X$ symmetric for bounded $X$ without characteristic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1842970/442)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ have density
$$
f(x) = \frac1{48}\left(1-\mathsf{sign}(x)\sin\left(|x|^{\frac14}\right)\right) e^{-|x|^{\frac14}},\ x\in\mathbb R.
$$
Then for each positive integer $n$ we have
$$
\mathbb E[X^n] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n f(x)\ \mathsf dx = \frac{(1+(-1)^n)(4(n+1))!}{12}.
$$
It follows immediately that $\mathbb E[X^{2n+1}=0]$ for all nonnegative integers $n$. It is clear though that $f$ is not an even function, so $X$ is not symmetric about zero.

Comment: Source: https://telescoper.wordpress.com/2018/07/09/the-problem-with-odd-moments/